# Reading application.properties from any class in spring boot

Tags: properties, spring-boot

When I add a property in the application.properties files, this can be access from the main class without any problem.

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.*")
    public class MailTestApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

        @Value("${admin.mail}")
        String email;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(MailTestApplication.class, args);
        }

        @Override
        public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {

            System.out.println(email);
            Email email = new Email();
            email.sendMail();
        }
    }
```

However, when I try to access it from any other class it is never retrieved.

```
    @Component
    public class Email {

        @Autowired
        private MailSender sender;

        @Value("${admin.mail}")
        String email;

        public Email() {
        }

        public void sendMail() {
            SimpleMailMessage msg = new SimpleMailMessage();

            System.out.println(email);

            msg.setTo("sample@email.com");
            msg.setSubject("Send mail by Spring Boot");
            msg.setText("Send mail by Spring Boot");

            sender.send(msg);
        }
    }
```

I was reading some of the previous questions other users posted without a clear result for me. I even tried to find some examples with similar resutl.

Could someone give me any clue about this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: If you have seen any error.  Paste the stacktrace here.

Comment: There is no error at all regarding to the property reading. The issue is the value is always null when I try to read it from any class that is not the main one.

Comment: I'm not familiar with spring boot. I suspect it could be an issue of scope or dependency. I would suggest you to fetch that property in main class, store in a member variable, create getters and setters and try to access the getter methods of the variable from other classes by injecting main class instance. This approach would be better as you don't repeatedly access the property file.

Comment: That could be a workaround but not a solution itself. I rather prefer to know how it really works to better understand the framework.

Comment: ok.. cool.. This link might help you. http://blog.codeleak.pl/2013/11/how-to-propertysource-annotations-in.html

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but I've always favored injecting Environment into my components and reading properties from it.  I find it a bit cleaner.

Comment: Is the Email class a Spring bean? (ie. is it annotated with @Component etc.)

Comment: @kryger I tried before with it with no success. The code I posted is a sample code I created to focus on this concrete problem.

In order to make it even easier, I put the class Email in the same package as the main class to avoid any configuration issue.

Comment: Being in the same package isn't enough. It needs to be annotated with `@Component` to be picked up by component scanning. Can you update your question with a complete example showing how you're getting an instance of `Email` and calling `sendMail` on it?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I just updated it. I have to say if I create the object instance with Autowired I get this error:

Could not autowire field: com.example.Email com.example.MailTestApplication.emailComponent; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.Email] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

If I keep it as shown I get the null result initaly said.

Answer (score 1):

The @Value should work (Im asuming your class is under the com.example.* package since you are scanning that package) but if you want to do it another way this is what im using :

```
public class JpaConfiguration {

    public static final String TRANSACTION_MANAGER_NAME = "jpaTransactionManager";

    @Autowired
    Environment applicationProperties;
```

Then to use it

```
@Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource driverConfig = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        driverConfig.setDriverClassName(applicationProperties.getProperty("data.jpa.driverClass"));
        driverConfig.setUrl(applicationProperties
                .getProperty("data.jpa.connection.url"));
        driverConfig.setUsername(applicationProperties
                .getProperty("data.jpa.username"));
        driverConfig.setPassword(applicationProperties
                .getProperty("data.jpa.password"));

        return driverConfig;
    }
```

UPDATE AFTER GETTING THE GITHUB REPO

I Don't really know what you are trying to build but :

If you do this:

```
@Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {

        //System.out.println(email);
        Email email = new Email();
        email.sendMail();
    }
```

Then you are creating the instance of the class, and not spring. so you shouldn't be creating the instance yourself there it should be spring.
That said, i dont know if you are creating a web application a command line application or both.

That said ill give you a minor solution to show you that the dependency injection is in fact working.

1_ add a getter to your email on email class. remove the CommandLine interface (If you want to implement this i would recomend you to put CommandLine implmentations on another package say Controller);

And then run your app like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example")
public class MailTestApplication  {

    @Value("${admin.mail}")
    String email;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // SpringApplication.run(MailTestApplication.class, args);

        final ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(MailTestApplication.class).run(args);

        Email e = context.getBean(Email.class);
        System.out.println(e.getEmail());
    }
```

The Key thing I want to show is that the instance is created by spring thats why the wiring works. and the email gets printed in the console.
Regarding the email class :

```
@Component
public class Email {

//    @Autowired
  //  private MailSender sender;

    @Value("${admin.mail}")
    String email;

    public Email() {
    }

    public void sendMail() {
        SimpleMailMessage msg = new SimpleMailMessage();

        System.out.println(email);

        msg.setTo("sample@email.com");
        msg.setSubject("Send mail by Spring Boot");
        msg.setText("Send mail by Spring Boot");

       // sender.send(msg);
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }


}
```

I Comment out the MailSender since I think you need to configure that too, i have made a custom mailSender that uses gmail and other for mailChimp that i can share with you if you need. but again I dont really know what your intent with the app is.

Hope the info helps you.

Comment: Thanks @Sudakatux for your answer. In my case both are in the same package and still not working. 

In case they are in different packages I guess adding the ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.*") should be enough if I make it work in the same package first actually.

Comment: Ok but your mailSenderService is in fact being injected right?

Comment: Neither! The MailSender is also null. I think it is because of the same reason.

Comment: Ok your MailSender (Assuming custom made )  Should be in the package com.example.{somechild} and this class should also be in that package or child otherwise spring will not make an instance out of them. if you would like to scan more than one package you can do this ```@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.asimplemodule.controller",
  "com.asimplemodule.config",
  "com.asimplemodule.security"})``` Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, all classes are in the same pacakge in order to avoid any settings issue.

Comment: Could you please share your directory structure?  with an image or with the tree command?

Comment: com.example.MailTestApplication   com.example.Email


If you wanna check it, this is my github repo for this sample:
https://github.com/MichaelKnight/applicationpropertiesread.git

Thaks for your help by the way.

Comment: No problem edited my response, it should probably get you going

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98484/discussion-between-michael-knight-and-sudakatux).